# What are contraction funds?

Tags: hoa

This section of bylaws for a Homeowners association reads:

[image]

What is a contraction fund?  Specifically what does contraction imply?

Comment: I think that is an "auto correct" error, I believe it should be "construction funds". Contraction wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Plausible response.

Comment: Especially since the clause above says *"separate construction funds"*, I'd chalk this up to a spelling mistake, which doesn't mean that the clause is void.

Comment: Almost any judge or jury would conclude that this is a typo that has no legal effect.